# Using the log directive in Caddy for both stdout and stderr

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

Reading through the [Caddy docs for `log` directive](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/log#stdout), I am unsure how to modify the `Caddyfile` if we want to log both `stdout` and `stderr`.

I tried starting Caddy without errors using the following `Caddyfile` but I am unsure how to test that it is actually logging both stdout and stderr. Will appreciate some help here. Thanks!

```
my.website.com {
    reverse_proxy localhost:3000

    log {
        output stdout
        level DEBUG
    }

    log {
        output stderr
        level DEBUG
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe all logs are written to the output you select, so all logs to stdout, or stderr, or in your case both. You could probably test with running the caddy binary with this config and checking which pipe it outputs the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Put the logging block outside the server block:

```
{
    log {
        level DEBUG
    }
}
my.website.com {
    reverse_proxy localhost:3000
}
```